# Image gallery using jQuery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
<div id="w01">
<img src=qa/01.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=qa/02.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=qa/03.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=qa/04.jpg alt='img'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#w01 > img{
    display:none;
    width:100%;
}
#w01 > img:first-child{
    display:block;
}
```

This is starting position. All images are hidden except the first one.
Now I want to create an image gallery using jQuery array.
Click on Next button should move the first image at the bottom of stack, and display the next one.

```
var arr = $("#w01 > img").toArray();

$('.next').click(function(){
    var first = arr[0];
    arr.shift(first);
    arr[1].show(); //error
});
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Is something wrong in the concept, or just in the code, or both?

Comment: your code is included inside $(document).ready()?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, yes it is. `alert (arr);` gives me img objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = $("#w01 > img").toArray();

$('.next').click(function(){
    var first = arr[0];
    arr.shift(first);
    arr[1].show(); //error
});
```

Change to:

```
var arr = $("#w01 > img").toArray();

$('.next').click(function(){
    // var first = arr[0];
    // arr.shift(first);
    // $(arr[1]).show(); // This will not show any error. But it will not work as you expected.
    // See A. Wolff's comment for more details.

    // New
    $(arr[0]).hide(); // Hide showing img
    arr.push(arr.shift()); // Shift array
    $(arr[0]).show(); // Show new first img
});
```

Because `arr[1]` returns a pure Javascript DOM, while `.show` is a method of jQuery.

Comment: I guess it should be: `$(arr[0]).show();` and BTW should use: `arr.push(arr.shift(first));`, `shift()` removing first item from array

Comment: Reegan, why image switching is stopped when reached the last image? It should display the first image again, in an endless circle !